# RabbitMq with reactJS

Tags: javascript, reactjs, rabbitmq

I'm trying to consume messages from frontend using rabbitMq, 
I already have rabbitMq and queue with data.
I searched for rabbitMq for react-Js or JavaScript but I didn't find any useful information.

so How I can consume from the rabbitMq using javaScript/react-Js

Thanks.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Well RabbitMQ is just the broker so you could use any MQTT pkg that fits RabbitMQ's requisites.

One example is [MQTT.js](https://www.npmjs.com/package/mqtt)